# I am sending this code to email but it is not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, email

*I am sending this code to the email, but It is not coming responsive in the mobile view. I have CSS and HTML code. I am not expert in the CSS please make my code correct for mobile view in the mobile. When I check it in the web it is working fine but when I send it to email it is not responsive. Please look into the code and find the errors.*

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
            .container {
                max-width: 650px;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .container {
                max-width: 760px;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 769px) {
            [data-hide-on="desktop"] {
                display: none !important;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            [data-hide-on="mobile"] {
                display: none !important;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            [builder-element=CellContainerElement].cell-responsive {
                display: block !important;
            }

            [builder-element=CellContainerElement].cell-responsive [builder-element="CellElement"] {
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: none !important;
            }

            [builder-element=CellContainerElement].cell-responsive [builder-element="CellElement"],
            [builder-element=CellContainerElement].cell-responsive [builder-element="BlockElement"] {
                padding-left: 0px !important;
                padding-right: 0px !important;
            }

            /* EmailMode */
            [builder-element=CellContainerElement].cell-responsive tbody,
            [builder-element=CellContainerElement].cell-responsive tr,
            [builder-element=CellContainerElement].cell-responsive td {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100%;
            }

            [builder-element=CellContainerElement].cell-responsive [builder-element="CellElement"] td {
                padding-left: 0px !important;
                padding-right: 0px !important;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 600px) {
            [builder-element=PricingTableElement] .col-12 {
                flex-basis: 0;
                flex-grow: 1;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 500px) {
            [builder-element="CellElement"] {
                display: block;
width:100%;
                /* Add any other custom styles you want for [builder-element="CellElement"] when viewport width is below 500px */
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="AcelleSystemLayouts">
    <title>1-2 column layout</title>

    <link
        href="/assets/YXBwL2N1c3RvbWVycy82NGEyYzVhMjgzM2I0L2hvbWUvdGVtcGxhdGVzLzY0YmNhY2VlNTJhZWUvY3Nz/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/YXBwL2N1c3RvbWVycy82NGEyYzVhMjgzM2I0L2hvbWUvdGVtcGxhdGVzLzY0YmNhY2VlNTJhZWUvY3Nz/custom.css"
        rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="builderjs-layout">
    <!--[if mso]>
        <center>
        <table><tr><td width="760">
    <![endif]-->
    <div builder-element="PageElement" style="padding-top:50px;padding-bottom:50px;">
        <table width="100%" builder-element="BlockElement" class="">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px">
                        <div class="container">
                            <table builder-element="CellContainerElement" data-layout="5-5" border="0" cellpadding="0"
                                cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td builder-element="CellElement" valign="top" width="50%"
                                            class="responsive-column">
                                            <table width="100%" builder-element="BlockElement">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px">
                                                            <div class="container">
                                                                <img builder-element=""
                                                                    src="/assets/YXBwL2N1c3RvbWVycy82NGEyYzVhMjgzM2I0L2hvbWUvdGVtcGxhdGVzLzY0YmNhY2VlNTJhZWUvaW1hZ2U/logo.png"
                                                                    width="200">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td builder-element="CellElement" valign="top" width="50%"
                                            class="responsive-column">
                                            <table width="100%" builder-element="BlockElement">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px">
                                                            <div class="container">
                                                                <p builder-element=""
                                                                    style="text-align:right;margin-bottom:0;">
                                                                    <a builder-element="" href=""
                                                                        style="color: #333;">Open in your
                                                                        browser</a>
                                                                </p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table width="100%" builder-element="BlockElement">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px">
                        <div class="container">
                            <h1 builder-element="" builder-inline-edit="" class="display-4" style="text-align:center;">
                                Lorem ipsum
                                dolor</h1>
                            <h5 builder-element="" builder-inline-edit="" class="font-weight-normal mt-1 mb-3"
                                style="text-align:center;">Nunc pulvinar turpis sed pellentesque aliquet</h5>
                            <p builder-element="" builder-inline-edit="" class="">Vestibulum id convallis ligula.
                                Maecenas tellus
                                erat, porta in augue eget, pretium aliquet neque. Nunc pulvinar turpis sed pellentesque
                                aliquet. Sed ullamcorper, tellus eu viverra tincidunt, quam justo pellentesque est, et
                                gravida justo eros vitae turpis. Mauris molestie id nisi in ultrices. Curabitur tellus
                                ex,
                                pretium nec dui ut, feugiat semper ipsum. Donec porttitor congue blandit. Pellentesque
                                in
                                purus nulla. Integer ut turpis purus. Nunc nec efficitur nunc.</p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table width="100%" builder-element="BlockElement" class="">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div style="text-align:center">
                                <img builder-element="" class=""
                                    src="/assets/YXBwL2N1c3RvbWVycy82NGEyYzVhMjgzM2I0L2hvbWUvdGVtcGxhdGVzLzY0YmNhY2VlNTJhZWUvaW1hZ2U/banner_1920_640.png"
                                    width="100%">
                            </div>
                            <h2 builder-element="" builder-inline-edit="" class="mt-3">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
                            <p builder-element="" builder-inline-edit="" class="">Vestibulum id convallis ligula.
                                Maecenas tellus erat,
                                porta in augue eget, pretium aliquet neque.
                                Nunc pulvinar turpis sed pellentesque aliquet. Sed ullamcorper, tellus eu viverra
                                tincidunt,
                                quam justo pellentesque est, et gravida justo eros vitae turpis. Mauris molestie id nisi
                                in
                                ultrices.
                                Curabitur tellus ex, pretium nec dui ut, feugiat semper ipsum. Donec porttitor congue
                                blandit.
                                Pellentesque in purus nulla. Integer ut turpis purus. Nunc nec efficitur nunc.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table width="100%" builder-element="BlockElement" class="">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px">
                        <div class="container">
                            <table builder-element="CellContainerElement" data-layout="5-5" border="0" cellpadding="0"
                                cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td builder-element="CellElement" valign="top" width="50%"
                                            class="responsive-column">
                                            <table width="100%" builder-element="BlockElement" class="">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td
                                                            style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-right:15px;">
                                                            <div class="container">
                                                                <img builder-element="" builder-inline-edit=""
                                                                    class="my-2 image-after-change"
                                                                    src="https://picsum.photos/200" width="100%">
                                                                <h3 builder-element="" builder-inline-edit=""
                                                                    class="mt-2 mb-2">Lorem
                                                                    ipsum dolor</h3>
                                                                <p builder-element="" builder-inline-edit="" class="">
                                                                    Vestibulum id convallis
                                                                    ligula. Maecenas tellus erat, porta in augue eget,
                                                                    pretium
                                                                    aliquet neque.
                                                                    Nunc pulvinar turpis sed pellentesque aliquet. Sed
                                                                    ullamcorper,
                                                                    tellus eu viverra tincidunt,
                                                                    quam justo p
                                                                </p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td builder-element="CellElement" valign="top" width="50%"
                                            class="responsive-column">
                                            <table width="100%" builder-element="BlockElement" class="">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td
                                                            style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-left:15px;">
                                                            <div class="container">
                                                                <img builder-element="" builder-inline-edit=""
                                                                    class="my-2 image-after-change"
                                                                    src="https://picsum.photos/200" width="100%">
                                                                <h3 builder-element="" builder-inline-edit=""
                                                                    class="mt-2 mb-2">Lorem
                                                                    ipsum dolor</h3>
                                                                <p builder-element="" builder-inline-edit="" class="">
                                                                    Vestibulum id convallis
                                                                    ligula. Maecenas tellus erat, porta in augue eget,
                                                                    pretium
                                                                    aliquet neque.
                                                                    Nunc pulvinar turpis sed pellentesque aliquet. Sed
                                                                    ullamcorper,
                                                                    tellus eu viverra tincidunt,
                                                                    quam justo p
                                                                </p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table width="100%" builder-element="BlockElement">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div builder-element="IconsContainerElement" class="" style="text-align: center;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:inline;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 15px">
                                                <a builder-element="IconLinkElement" data-value="facebook" href=""
                                                    class="d-inline-block">
                                                    <span class="social-icon">
                                                        <img src="/assets/YXBwL2N1c3RvbWVycy82NGEyYzVhMjgzM2I0L2hvbWUvdGVtcGxhdGVzLzY0YmNhY2VlNTJhZWUvaW1hZ2UvaWNvbnM/facebook.png"
                                                            height="35" width="auto">
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 15px">
                                                <a builder-element="IconLinkElement" data-value="linkedin" href=""
                                                    class="d-inline-block">
                                                    <span class="social-icon">
                                                        <img src="/assets/YXBwL2N1c3RvbWVycy82NGEyYzVhMjgzM2I0L2hvbWUvdGVtcGxhdGVzLzY0YmNhY2VlNTJhZWUvaW1hZ2UvaWNvbnM/linkedin.png"
                                                            height="35" width="auto">
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 15px">
                                                <a builder-element="IconLinkElement" data-value="youtube" href=""
                                                    class="d-inline-block">
                                                    <span class="social-icon">
                                                        <img src="/assets/YXBwL2N1c3RvbWVycy82NGEyYzVhMjgzM2I0L2hvbWUvdGVtcGxhdGVzLzY0YmNhY2VlNTJhZWUvaW1hZ2UvaWNvbnM/youtube.png"
                                                            height="35" width="auto">
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 15px">
                                                <a builder-element="IconLinkElement" data-value="twitter" href=""
                                                    class="d-inline-block">
                                                    <span class="social-icon">
                                                        <img src="/assets/YXBwL2N1c3RvbWVycy82NGEyYzVhMjgzM2I0L2hvbWUvdGVtcGxhdGVzLzY0YmNhY2VlNTJhZWUvaW1hZ2UvaWNvbnM/twitter.png"
                                                            height="35" width="auto">
                                                    </span>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table width="100%" builder-element="BlockElement">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="text-muted">

                                <div builder-element="TextElement">
                                    <p class="m-0" style="text-align: center;padding-bottom:5px;">Copyright © 2022. All
                                        rights reserved.</p>
                                    <p class="m-0" style="text-align: center;padding-bottom:5px;">You can <a
                                            builder-element="" href="{UPDATE_PROFILE_URL}">update your preferences</a>
                                        or <a builder-element="" href="{UNSUBSCRIBE_URL}">unsubscribe from this
                                            list</a>.</p>
                                </div>

                                <p builder-element="" builder-inline-edit=""
                                    style="text-align: center;margin-top: 15px;font-size: 13px;">
                                    <a builder-element="" href="#" style="color:#555;">Back to top</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!--[if mso]>
        </td></tr></table>
        </center>
    <![endif]-->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Email is still in the dark ages, so most CSS is unreliable there. Best to check what's supported in email first. You'll be disappointed. Some email clients barely support any of this stuff.

Comment: This site gives some clues as to which systems support what. As @ralph.m has indicated, a lot isn’t supported across the board e.g. flex. https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=F